# Is it possible to implement RS flip flop truth table in Python?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, flip-flop

I am new to Python. i am using Spyder (pandas and numpy) to run an algorithm for data analysis. This requires implementation of an RS flip flop on two variables in the data.
something like this in C:

```
((R_b) != FALSE) ? (*(State_pb) = FALSE) : (((S_b) != FALSE) ? (*(State_pb) = TRUE) : *(State_pb));
```

Here R_b is the R input to the flip-flop and S-b is the S input. Note the use of pointer to the previous state of the flip flop to retain previous state . Could this be implemented in Python as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a function that's a fairly direct translation of your C code, using Python's conditional operator.

```
from itertools import product

def flipflop(state, r, s):
    return False if r else (True if s else state)

# test

print('state : r, s -> new_state')
for state, r, s in product((False, True), repeat=3):
    print('{!s:5} : {!s:5}, {!s:5} -> {!s:5}'.format(state, r, s, flipflop(state, r, s)))
```

**output**

```
state : r, s -> new_state
False : False, False -> False
False : False, True  -> True 
False : True , False -> False
False : True , True  -> False
True  : False, False -> True 
True  : False, True  -> True 
True  : True , False -> False
True  : True , True  -> False
```

Note that neither this code nor your C code correctly handle the forbidden `r == s == True` input.

Comment: Thanks for the snippet! It does need the initial state then to begin with. And about the r==s==True , it is ensured in the system design that it doesn't occur.

Comment: @VinayakR The Python version has to work a little differently to the C version, since Python doesn't have pointers, per se. In fact, it doesn't have C-like variables. Please see [Other languages have "variables", Python has "names"](http://python.net/~goodger/projects/pycon/2007/idiomatic/handout.html#other-languages-have-variables).

Comment: @VinayakR I guess you _could_ do this using a custom class to hold the state, with a method that handles the updating; the class constructor would initialise the flip-flop to a known state. It would only be a few lines of code, but IMHO that's probably overkill for this application.

Comment: You are right. It would be overkill. I think, for now, I can just initialize the state to 0 or use proper indexing in the data to assign the previous state . Thanks for the help. PS: the article u shared is awesome